# Multipeer chaining

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I've done some testing with the new Multipeer framework in iOS and it seems that when on bluetooth only (wifi turned off), two devices that are more than 30 feet away from each other can't see each other as peers, even if there is another device in between them.

For example, Device A and Device B are connected and within 30 feet from each other. Device B and C are connected to each other and within 30 feet from each other.  Is it possible for Device A and Device C to see each other and communicate back and forth? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum effective range of bluetooth is around 15 feet. Multipeer connectivity just simplifies communication between the devices in range to them. If you would like to perform networking in a web, or client server architecture, you'll have to implement that yourself.

### Client-Server

Device B will re-transmit messages from any device to all devices.

### Web

All Devices will re-transmit any message to all devices.

Comment: Thank you. What about increasing the number of peers beyond the max of 8? Is it possible to do with creating new sessions but still allowing all of the peers on all sessions to communicate with each other?

Comment: Clients on separate sessions will not be able by default to comunicate each other. You need to make your server resent the data if you want that function